# Copy an android app from my phone to my PC

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-sdk-tools

I don't know if what I am going to ask is possible.  As a matter of fact, I can see that it would be a bad idea, but I thought I would ask just in case.  I have an app on my phone that I have been working on in my lab at school.  I am stuck at home now and would like to continue working on the app here at home but all my code is on my computer at school.  Is there any way to move the app from my phone to my PC so that I can continue working on the app in eclipse?

Thanks

Comment: All these things are possible, but are you sure it's really what you want?  The best you could do is extract the APK and then de-compile it.  But you will have lost plenty of value in the code like comments and potentially lots of details if you used proguard.  You might be better off just waiting until you have access to the original code again.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input. Once I knew it was possible, I figured out how to do it. And you were correct; it is not straight forward. If not for the fact that I originally wrote the code myself, I am not sure I could have recovered it. This turned out to be a good exercise and I learned to use some cool tools.

Answer (score 2):

As Scott says, simply copying the app to your PC will not exactly allow you to develop as though you have the source code in front of you, but if you insist, you'll need root access to get a directory listing of your /data directory, then you'll need to `adb pull` the file.

Answer (score 0):

You are working on an app in school ? ok, so let me guess. are your using eclipse ide to create that app ? if yes, then you can simply copy the whole project and paste it in your pc and run it there from eclipse.

If it is only an app on your mobile , then you can use BlueStack Placer on your PC

Extract the apk of your app from mobile using an application called **apk extractor**. It is stored in a predefined folder. Connect your phone to PC , copy that apk n a folder i have described below. It must be in a folder called **Apk Extractor**.

Now, install BlueStack Player. Basically it is a player to run android apps.

Copy the APK file into the `Apps` folder, which is created by default in the Libraries folder at the time of BlueStacks installation. Right click on that APK file and open with apk handler.exe which is located in `C:\Program Files\blue stack`(Your BlueStack installation Location)

Your app has been installed in BlueStack Player. It will show on the home screen of the Player

**NOTE :- These instructions are tested and i have run it**

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input. I figured out a way to do it.  What I did seems to be more convoluted than what you suggest above, but it worked.  I am using eclipse. I left the project on my computer at school but it looks like I might not be able to get back in for a few days because of the weather and I really wanted to work some more on the project.  I should have checked it into subversion, but oh well.

Comment: That is what i was saying when you meant by app. It must be a project on eclipse